# How to get a node with specific value in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, traversal

I want to get a node with bno(branch number).

```
struct bank {
    struct branch *branches; // to hold the branches of the bank
    struct operation_type *optypes; // to hold the transaction types offered by the bank
};
```

```
struct branch *getProperBranch(struct bank *banka, int entity) {
    while (banka->branches != NULL) {
        if (banka->branches->bno == entity) {
            return banka->branches;
        }
        banka->branches = banka->branches->nextb;
    }
}
```

When I do this I can find it but `bank->branches` address is changed. I lose its original values. How can I do this without losing position?
I need to access `bank->branches->customers` and add new customer in a proper location.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a copy: `struct bank *bptr = banka->branches;` and use that the search the list.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you. I've learned that I need a copy of original head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable with the type of your node. Don't forget the return value in the event `entity` is not found.

```
struct branch *getProperBranch(struct bank *banka, int entity) {
    for (struct branch *bp = banka->branches; bp; bp = bp->nextb)
        if (bp->bno == entity) 
            return bp;                                                  
                               
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I struggle to understand the logic behind the copy of the original node. After creating a copy, copy and original nodes points to the same address so that we can make changes in the original node's subnodes. What is the point of it?

Comment: `banka->branches = banka->branches->nextb;` changes the pointer value held by the `bank` structure's `branches` member. `bp = bp->nextb` only changes the pointer value held by the temporary variable.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you.@Oka I am gonna think about the concept behind it. I still think if I change temp->val it is also gonna change original->val.